# ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __divdi3

Tags: clang, llvm, riscv, lld

I'm trying to link two risc-v elf files together with `ld.lld`, but `ld.lld` is giving me the following error:

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: __divdi3
```

I suppose that I need to link my files with some helper functions, but after looking for it in my clang lib folder (`/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/15.0.6/lib/clang/15.0.6/lib`), but in the directory, there is only a folder for darwin, as you can see here:

```
.
└── darwin
    ├── libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib
    ├── libclang_rt.cc_kext.a
    ├── libclang_rt.fuzzer_interceptors_osx.a
[more]
    ├── libclang_rt.xray-profiling_osx.a
    └── libclang_rt.xray_osx.a
```

So does anyone know how should I fix this link error/get the rv64i helper functions?

Thanks!

Edit: Here are the commands that I used:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/15.0.6/bin/clang --target=riscv64 -march=rv64i  -fno-builtin -nostdlib -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -pedantic -c -o build/main.o bios/main.c
riscv64-unknown-elf-as -march=rv64i -o build/start.o src/start.S
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/15.0.6/bin/ld.lld -T link.ld -O2 -nostdlib --oformat=binary -o output.bin build/main.o build/start.o
```

Comment: 1) Could you share the command used? 2) Is this reproducable with using gcc instead of clang? If not, it might be related to a current clang issue.

Comment: @Krokomot Just edited my post to include the commands I used. Also idk if this is reproducable with using gcc, didn't try, but I think it is only a clang issue, since each compiler has it's own helper functions

Comment: the .o is with the `-o` file, which specifies the name of the output file, `build/main.o` is not a input

Comment: Have a nice break!

Comment: You probably need to link the library output by `clang -print-libgcc-file-name`. Or just use `clang` as the linker command.

Comment: @user3840170 The file that clang gove me by using `clang -print-libgcc-file-name` doesn't exist on my computer, which is a bit weird, do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a copy of the source of the functions in libgcc here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/releases/gcc-12/libgcc/config/riscv Just copy them and place them in your source and they will compile for whatever arch your compiling for

The function `__divdi3` is in the div.c file

Comment: Note that this might impose additional licensing restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

`__divdi3` is as a routine from the compiler supporting library. In case of gcc it is called `libgcc`, in case of clang it's `compiler-rt`. You need to have `compiler-rt` built from the architecture in question (RISC-V) and make it available to compiler via e.g. sysroot or something similar (or link explicitly).

Alternatively, just do not use 64-bit division in your program, so the call will not be generated :)

Comment: But how do I get `compiler-rt` for rv64i?

Comment: Compile it from source? Or take from some RISC-V-aware sysroot?